# How to display a world texture as a spherical icon via Python?

Tags: python, node-editor, interface, world

I'm building some viewport display tools within a panel. I want to have a spherical icon display for the active world environment texture similar to the Material viewport HDR display. The material viewport hdr display uses template_icon_view:

```
layout.template_icon_view(shading, "studio_light", scale_popup=3.0)
```

So far, I've been unable to find any combination of data to feed this function to make it display the active world texture environment. I can use `layout.template_preview(world)` but this only displays a flat image sample of the environment. `template_preview()` has a parameter `preview_id` presumably to change the preview display type for input values like "MATERIAL" or "TEXTURE" etc. but no value I try here seems to change anything and I can't find a list of `preview_id` options. Is there some way to use either `template_icon_view()`, `template_preview()`, or some other template option available here: [UILayout](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html) to display the world environment texture as a spherical icon in a panel or menu?